# function that uses list comprehensions to generate a list of lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I want to write a function that uses list comprehensions to generate a list of lists that works like this:

```
makeList 3 == [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
makeList 5 == [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5]]
makeList (-2) == []
```

I end up with this solution, but It not gives me what it needs from the question obviously:

```
let makelist x = [x | x <- x, y <- [1..x]]
```

So if I enter this

```
Prelude> makelist [3]
```

the output will shows like this:

```
[3,3,3]
```

I wanted to be a list in list first then I want it to be increased. Thank you for help!

Comment: First of all, re-using variable names is probably not the best thing to do. `makelist x = [x | x <- x, ...]` is not good practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's try generating an inner list first, for some limit `m`:

```
> let inner m = [1..m]
> inner 5
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Now, observe that your outer list, for some limit `n`, is `[inner 1, inner 2, inner 3, ..., inner n]`, or, in list comprehension form:

```
> let outer n = [inner m | m <- [1..n]]
> outer 3
[[1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
```

so we can combine the two into the single list comprehension expression:

```
> let makeList n = [[1..m] | m <- [1..n]]
> makeList 4
[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

I propose you this:

```
make_list n = [ [1..m] | m <- [1..n] ]
```

---

However there's something strange in your first attempt:

```
make_list x = [x | x <- x, y <- [1..x]]
```

there you put x for every purpose. It just feels wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive version based in list generation as well,

```
makeList' :: Int -> [[Int]]
makeList' n
  | n < 1 = []
  | otherwise = [1..n] : makeList' (n-1)


makeList :: Int -> [[Int]]
makeList n = reverse $ makeList' n
```

`makeList'` returns the desired outcome in reverse order.